# How do I make a method that will be executed once and only once?

Tags: c#

In my program there is a screen with a "Print Receipt" button; on click of the button, I need to to call a method once and only once. Currently, the user can print multiple receipts and I do not know of a way to prevent this.

```
private async void PrintReceipt() 
{
    await _printReceiptInteractor.PrintTerminalReceiptAsync(_receipt).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => { this.Close(); });
}
```

How can I enforce the requirement of only executing this method once?

UPDATE: I manage to fix this by adding an IsBusy Property and and a method where i set IsBusy there , and just call that method , then i set IsBusy to false in the *finally* cause im using a try and catch statement.

Comment: add a boolean `bool _alreadyPrinted` set it to `true` if you printed the file. In your method check if its `true`, if so `return`.

Answer (score 2):

You will either need to disable the GUI control that calls your method or you will need to create a property to such as a bool to track the entry to your method.

```
private bool _executed = false;
private void Method()
{
    if(!_executed)
    {
        _executed = true;
        // ...
    }
}

private readonly Button _button = new Button();
private void Method()
{
    _button.Enabled = false;
    // ...
}

private readonly object _lockObj = new object();
private void Method()
{
    // Prevent concurrent access
    lock(_lockObj)
    {
        if(!_executed)
        {
            _executed = true;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private bool _printed = false;

private async void PrintReceipt()
{
    if(!_printed)
    {
        await _printReceiptInteractor.PrintTerminalReceiptAsync(_receipt).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => { this.Close(); });

        _printed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isbusy;
private async void PrintReceipt() 
{
    isbusy = true

    try
    {
      await _printReceiptInteractor.PrintTerminalReceiptAsync(_receipt)
    }
    finally
    {
       //This block will always exeute even if there is an exception
       isbusy = false
    }
}
```

The Print `Command` Here i have demoe

```
private ICommand _printCommand;
        public ICommand PrintCommand
        {
          get
          {
            return _printCommand ??(PrintCommand=
                   new RelayCommand(async () => await PrintReceipt(), CanExecute));
            }
        }


//Determine can execute command
private bool CanExecute()
{
      return !isbusy;
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<button Content="Print" Command={Binding PrintCommand"/>
```

> The Button will disabled in state when the `Command` cannot be executed, that is during system is busy.

I would recommend you to read a [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvvm/info)

Comment: Hey , thanks , your answer is more understandable and clear , i just start as a junior dev now , and im still confused about the codebase , theres already 


    "this._printReceiptCommandLazy = new Lazy<ICommand>(() => new DelegateCommand(PrintReceipt, CanPrintReceipt));"

and theres already a Command

    "private Lazy<ICommand> _printReceiptCommandLazy;
        public ICommand PrintReceiptCommand {
            get {
                return this._printReceiptCommandLazy.Value;
            }
        }"

how can i implement your suggestions here? thanks

Comment: heres the CanPrintReceipt method

    "private bool CanPrintReceipt() {
            return _receipt != null;
        }"

Comment: You dont need use the same code base i have suggested you can go with your `ICommand` and `CanPrintReceipt` Just add the command to your user button it will start working

Comment: Thanks you sir , fixed it :)